# Having trouble creating admin and user accounts using php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried these cocodes to insert data into the database and direct user to admin_dashboard.php but i always get the error message, What could be the problem. I am a beginner.

```
<?php 
require "../database_actions/db_connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['admbutton'])) {

    $Username = ($_POST['Username']);
    $Surname = ($_POST['Surname']);
    $Email = ($_POST['email']);
    $Password_1 = md5($_POST['password_1']);
    $Password_2 = ($_POST['Password_2']);
    $ID = ($_POST['aid']);




    $query = "INSERT INTO madmin(afname, asname, aimail, apassi, apassi01, aid) 
                    VALUES ('$Username', '$Surname', $Email, $Password_1, $Password_2, $ID)";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die("action failed" . mysqli_error($result));
        header("location: ../dashboards/admin_dashboard.php");


    }


}
```

Comment: "The error message" ? Also please learn about prepared statements, your script is wide open to SQL injection. And put a space between table name and "(".

Comment: Please share error message.

Comment: `$Username = ($_POST['Username']);` will be true or false... you need to validate all $_POST vars. like `$Username = ($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';`

Comment: Or `var_dump($query)` and check what's wrong with your query

Comment: Just to be sure double-check that your "db_connection.php" actually declares the $connection var, if so, watch out to the last "if". You are actually saying "If there's an error in the query (!$result) then die("action failed") and after that... nothing happens, your code will never reach header location because "die" actually kills the execution

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, i tried your suggestions but it seems i have an issue with my db connection because i tested my it with the following codes    
 but i don't see the record saved in the database  <?php  
$conn = mysqli_connect( 'localhost' , 'root' , '36121263' , 'majanga');

if (! $conn) { 
 echo "an error occured";
 # code...
}else{

 $query = "INSERT INTO madmin ( afname , asname , aimail , apassi , apassi01 , aid ) VALUES ( 'John Paul' , 'Onyango' , 'onyango.jpaul@gmail.com' , '543212' , '234564' , '123')";
}

mysqli_query($conn , $query);


?>

Answer (score 2):

Any number of issues could be your problem.

- An error in your connection string
- No connection to the database server
- Incorrect username or password for the connection to the database server
- Incorrect permissions for the user for the connection to the database server
- Firewall rules blocking connections to the database
- Mysql configuration options blocking your connection

and on and on.

Try to use [mysqli_error()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a more detailed description of what your issue might be.

Comment: Thank you everyone , after revising all your response to my question i discovered that i had problem with arranging brackets, braces and parenthesis. I think as a beginner it's important to take note of details.